# matplotlib ylabel TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have noticed some strange behavior that I can't understand in matplotlib.pyplot

When I call the ylabel method I get as TypeError as seen below. This does not happen with the xlabel method. The string value there is find and my plot prints.

What have I missed?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-5a3cfeebed52> in <module>()
      4 plt.grid(False)
      5 #plt.ylabel('Relative Search Freq')
----> 6 plt.ylabel('This is the Y Label')
      7 plt.xlabel('This is the X Label')
      8 plt.legend()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The plot does print but without the ylabel or any of the code after the error which seems normal behavior.

Comment: Have you set `plt.ylabel = 'some string'` somewhere further up in your code?

Comment: You have, at some point before running the code shown, redefined `plt.ylabel`. I.e. somewhere in your notebook you have written something like `plt.ylabel = "some string"`. From that point on, `plt.ylabel` is a string which cannot be called. Close your notebook or restart the kernel and you'll be fine.

Comment: I had to restart my kernel than the ylabel function worked.

Comment: Indeed, restarting the kernel fixed this problem 

Comment: Is there an alternative way of doing this? I would like not to restart my kernel. Many thanks. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer. Probably too late for you but, reload(plt) will also fix this. (In python 3 you need to import reload "from imp import reload")